# WiFi speed degraded upon clean installation of windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, dell-inspiron, wifi-driver

I was using windows 8.1. Now i have installed windows 10 on my laptop. But i have found that everything is working fine but wifi. My router's internet speed is 10mbps. But my laptop speed is strictly limited to 4mbps. I have installed three several copies of windows 10 .  But it remains same. I have updated wifi driver through windows update but not worked. 
I am using Dell N5110 laptop. 
Now what can i do?

Comment: Please ignore the current answer - do NOT install the old driver, it's likely to make things worse. Instead use https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html install and runs the Intel's tool. It detects and automatically suggests the proper up-to-date drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Trust not Windows Update, for it knows not what it does to third party equipment. Anyone who had nVidia video cards shortly after Win10's first slew of auto-updates knows this well.

It's a safe presumption that Windows will do nothing but check dates on drivers it can reach, compare them to drivers you have, and if it just "thinks" that the new driver is the right one, it will overwrite them.  What it will not do is check the manufacturer website; it gets its drivers from Microsoft's database.

[Download the driver specific to your machine here.](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15r-n5110/drivers) Please note that Windows 8 is as high as is supported by Dell for that equipment, but the Win8 driver will (most likely) work.

Comment: Intel provides up-to-date drivers for the Centrino wireless. Why are recommending a 5 years old driver for an older Windows version?

Comment: Because the on-die capabilities of the Intel chip are irrelevant here.  If you look at the machine options, there are two different discrete WiFi/BT solutions that came with those machines.  This is also an i5 unit.   Never trust a generic driver over something from the manufacturer when it comes to laptops; they're often custom tailored for the machine.

Comment: **They often lag behind when the manufacturer's support for a given model ends** and that's exactly the case here. Dell does not support Windows 10 for that machine but that doesn't mean it can't be used or that it requires the same (old and outdated) drivers, all the opposite actually. You're correct re: some components that are "tweaked" by the manufacturer and hence require (or prefer) "tweaked" drivers. **Not the case with WiFi or Ethernet chips** even when their firmware was modified to report as "Dell" instead of the real manufacturer.

Comment: The user's problem refects that this may be precisely the case, actually, thus the recommendation.  I've got a 10 year old Sager/Clevo custom unit which also *requires* older drivers for its WiFi or it behaves as if the physical network card switch has been toggled.  The only hardware in it which can use updated drivers now that it's fallen way out of support, in fact, is the video card, which could not use nVidia's driver set when the unit was new.

Comment: Assuming the user's problem is real and not a misinterpretation, an impression, or other fallacy as I strongly suspect it is (Reason: Windows 10 has good *native* support for any of the possible hardware combinations of that laptop. It's not plausible that it's slower know). Your N=1 level of expertise is what's irrelevant here, especially when compared to mine, and I don't mean only with different hardware but particularly as a former Dell Tech support manager.

Answer (score 0):

Get latest Dell wireless driver(no matter what is your wireless adapter)
After that do this:

1. Go to Network and Sharing Center
2. Change adapter settings
3. Right click on Wi-Fi adapter, select properties
4. Click on configure, then go to advanced tab
   5)Property:802.11n Value: 20/40 Auto
   If you don't get the latest wireless driver the last option didn't add in Property.

thanks to gadfly
source : https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/33600-very-slow-internet-after-upgrade-10-a-8.html